# Inkscape: how to create a polygon from several polylines?

Tags: inkscape, shapes

Drawn by hand in Inkscape, I have several polylines and polygons, more ore less in contact.

I want to build a polygon from them (in zone A) and fill it with a given colour. The desired polygon will have as border the small polyline on the right and a portion of the longer polyline on the left (that belongs to polygon B).
[image: Two path]
It is a cartography issue.

I tried several techniques but I am lost in the Inkscape menus. 
Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working from your example which has two paths, I'll call the path on the left "path 1" and the path on the right "path 2".

1. Ensure that path 2 is overlapping path 1 at the intersections, even if ever so slightly.
2. Select path 2, and choose Edit > Duplicate.
3. The duplicate of path 2 will now be placed on top of everything and selected. Keep it selected.
4. Hold shift and select path 1 as well.
5. Choose Path > Cut Path. Because path 1 is on bottom, it will be cut, and because the duplicate of path 2 is on top, it will be used to cut path 1. Path 1 will now be split into three parts, top, middle, and bottom; and the duplicate of path 2 will disappear.
6. Select the middle of path 1, and also path 2. Then choose Path > Combine.
7. We're almost there. With this new path selected, choose the node tool (you can press the "N" key), and zoom in to the two places in this path that need to be joined.
8. Select the two nodes that are very close together but not joined, and press the button on the Node Tool menu bar called "Join Selected Nodes". Do this for both of the break points in the path.
9. Voilà!

Comment: Well explained. One remark, I think in step 6 you can omit "Then choose Path > Combine", as this is done automatically in step 8. It is sufficient to select the two paths, then join the nodes.

Comment: Many thanks: I've tested it, it works. I have modified the picture to add the "path 1" and "path 2" to match your answer

Comment: I have difficulties reproducing the steps; it fails; it seems my objects are not path, and when I convert them from object to path, still I can't cut the path in the bottom

Comment: for some reason I do not understand, in addition to the 8 steps above in some cases I had to do Path->"Break Apart", or in other situations when this last function did not work to do Path->"Break path at selected nodes". In this last situation the cutter path disappeared and a new node appeared at the cutting point but I had to use this new node to cut and then "Break apart" the path.